# How can I both count total result and group them?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, group-by

Here is my table:

```
// posts
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
| id |   title   |        body        |  author_id | amount |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
| 1  | post1     | somthing           | 2543       | 5000   |
| 2  | post2     | something else     | 4352       | NULL   |
| 3  | post3     | whatever           | 1563       | 1200   |
| 4  | post4     | test context       | 7234       | NULL   |
| 5  | post5     | anything ...       | 4352       | NULL   |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
```

Also I have these two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(amount) FROM posts
+----------+---------------+
| COUNT(*) | COUNT(amount) |
+----------+---------------+
| 5        | 2             |
+----------+---------------+

SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,2
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
| id |   title   |        body        |  author_id | amount |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
| 1  | post1     | somthing           | 2543       | 5000   |
| 2  | post2     | something else     | 4352       | NULL   |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+
```

---

Now I want to combine those two queries and this is expected result:

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| id |   title   |        body        |  author_id | amount | COUNT(*) | COUNT(amount) |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| 1  | post1     | somthing           | 2543       | 5000   | 5        | 2             |
| 2  | post2     | something else     | 4352       | NULL   | 5        | 2             |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

How can I achieve that? And here is what I've tried so far which is wrong, it always returns one row:

```
SELECT x.*, COUNT(*), COUNT(amount)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id
) x
LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: cross join the second query to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're after correctly.  cross joining the queries shoudl do the trick..

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, COUNT(amount) cntamt FROM posts) t
ORDER BY p.id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

ALTERNATE maybe (UNTESTED)... but again a subquery...but only 1 where clause.

```
SELECT id, title, body, author_id, max(cnt) cnt, max(cntAmount) cntAmount
FROM (SELECT id
           , title
           , body
           , author_id
           , @cnt=@cnt+1 as cnt
           , case when Amount is not null then @cntamt:=@cntAmt+1 else @cntAmt end as cntAmount
      FROM posts p
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0,@cntAmt:=0) t
      GROUP BY id, title, body, author_id) Z
ORDER BY z.id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: Well [in reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566376/how-can-i-use-sub-query-to-count-the-result-before-limiting) those two queries have an identical and complex `where` clause, and I'm trying to improve the performance and match the result once. But in your case, still you're selecting twice.

Comment: If mySQL supported window/analytical functions then this could be achieved in 1 query.  However, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. Just why did you use the name of all columns in the `select` statement? Why not just `*` ?

Comment: habit.  since I had to group by the columns, I list them in the select.  in addition if the table structure changes (new columns) or the order of the columns, my select wouldn't be impacted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `CROSS JOIN`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    posts.*,
    tbl.nbr,
    tbl.nbrAmount 
FROM 
    posts 
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as nbr, COUNT(amount) as nbrAmount FROM posts) AS tbl
ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,2
```

Comment: Well [in reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566376/how-can-i-use-sub-query-to-count-the-result-before-limiting) those two queries have an identical and complex `where` clause, and I'm trying to improve the performance and match the result once. But in your case, still you're selecting twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using Join You can Combine this.

```
SELECT p1.*,p2.* FROM posts AS p1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(amount) FROM posts
) AS p2 ON 1=1
ORDER BY p1.id LIMIT 0,2
```